# Getting back to the console in Java

Tags: java, stdout

I'm writing a Java class which plugs into a larger framework. Somewhere upstream, the code is redirecting System.out to somewhere other than standard out, but I really want to print a debugging message to standard out. Is there a way for me to get a hook back into standard out?

Comment: Find out where it's pointing it to, and point *that* back to stdout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `System.err`?

The most straightforward solution I see is just store `System.out` somewhere in your class before calling the library.

After looking around a bit, you should be able to use `System.console().printf(...)`.

Comment: It seems to be eating System.err too. I am the downstream class, so I don't have the option of modifying my caller. System.console().printf looks like it should work. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps an easier solution is to use System.err instead of System.out for debugging messages?  It would be a lot easier and would not introduce any side-effects of that redirection.

Comment: Similarly, you could use a Java Logger, with a ConsoleHandler, which writes to System.err. This is a little more work, but can give you access to your debug messages outside the development environment.

Comment: It seems to be eating System.err too.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write:

```
System.setOut(System.out);
```